# Backup & migrate install error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have installed Drupal 7 and I am trying to install the Backup & Migrate module. I am getting the following error:

> Warning: fileowner(): stat failed for temporary://updD58A.tmp in update_manager_local_transfers_allowed()
>          (line 932 of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DrupalDev\modues\update\update.manager.inc).

Anyone know how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `admin/config/media/file-system` to manage file system settings and make sure to set the value of `Temporary directory` to a valid folder.

You can set the value of `Temporary directory` to `/tmp`.

I believe you will not be able to upload any file till you solve this issue.